# SwiftUI: How to delete a view after a certain time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this animation code:

```
struct CheckmarkAnimation: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(to: isAnimating ? 1:0)
                .stroke(.green, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: isAnimating)
            
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.5 : 0)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.4).delay(1), value: isAnimating)
        }
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like this view to disappear after the scaling effect on the checkmark ends. How do I do this?

Comment: Which view? if you mean `CheckmarkAnimation` then it should be not here, but in parent view.

Comment: You can potentially have another bool `shouldAppear`, and use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)` to toggle it.

Comment: Thank you! 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {shouldAppear = true} does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways to do it:

### Change drawing color to `.clear` after 2 seconds

Here’s a way to have it disappear (turn invisible but still take up space). Change the drawing color to `.clear` after 2 seconds:

```
struct CheckmarkAnimation: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    @State private var color = Color.green
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(to: isAnimating ? 1:0)
                .stroke(color, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: isAnimating)
            
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.5 : 0.001)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.4).delay(1), value: isAnimating)
                
        }
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating.toggle()
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.01).delay(2)) {
                color = .clear
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Use `.scaleEffect()` on `ZStack`

Insert this scale animation before the `.onAppear`:

```
.scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 0.001 : 1)
.animation(.linear(duration: 0.01).delay(2), value: isAnimating)
.onAppear {
    isAnimating.toggle()
}
```

**Note**: Use `0.001` instead of `0` in `scaleEffect` to avoid

> *ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform*

messages in the console.

Comment: Write an answer showing the code you created using the comment.

Comment: I added a second method which is to just scale it to 0 after 2 seconds.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left to turn it green.  You should consider accepting the answer to your other question as well.

Answer (score 0):

.scaleEffect() on ZStack is an elegant solution.

```
struct CheckmarkAnimation: View {
    @State private var isAnimating = false
    @State private var color = Color.green
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(to: isAnimating ? 1:0)
                .stroke(color, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: isAnimating)
            
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .foregroundColor(color)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 1.5 : 0)
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.4).delay(1), value: isAnimating)
                
        }
        .scaleEffect(isAnimating ? 0 : 1)
        .animation(.linear(duration: 0.01).delay(2), value: isAnimating)
        .onAppear {
            isAnimating.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

This code works and makes the view disappear^^

Comment: This is a repeat of my answer.  Why don't you use your answer to highlight how you used `shouldAppear` with `DispatchQueue` from the comments.  That idea hasn't been documented by an answer yet, and many people skip the comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).